# Как вставить svg в переменную SASS(SCSS)?

Tags: svg, sass

Вопрос довольно простой и глупый, но найти ответа на него я так и не смог самостоятельно(гуглил, подбирал значения, сидел с томным видом за размышлениями о смысле жизни svg).

Недавно я начал ознакамливаться с **svg** и бороздя просторы интернета, нашел неплохую *функцию* для преобразования **svg** кодировки в **URL**. Все это нужно, очевидно, для сокращения *http request-ов* на странице и всеми любимой автоматизации.

Ниже прилагаю код функции:

```css
@function svg-url($svg) {
  $encoded: '';
  $slice: 2000;
  $index: 0;
  $loops: ceil(str-length($svg)/$slice);
  @for $i from 1 through $loops {
    $chunk: str-slice($svg, $index, $index + $slice - 1);

    $chunk: str-replace($chunk, '"', '\'');
    $chunk: str-replace($chunk, '%', '%25');
    $chunk: str-replace($chunk, '&', '%26');
    $chunk: str-replace($chunk, '#', '%23');
    $chunk: str-replace($chunk, '{', '%7B');
    $chunk: str-replace($chunk, '}', '%7D');
    $chunk: str-replace($chunk, '<', '%3C');
    $chunk: str-replace($chunk, '>', '%3E');

    $encoded: #{$encoded}#{$chunk};
    $index: $index + $slice;
  }
  // sass-lint:disable quotes
  @return url("data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,#{$encoded}");
  // sass-lint:enable quotes
}

@mixin background-svg($svg) {
  background-image: svg-url($svg);
}
```

SVG код нужно вставить в переменную **$svg**, в этом и заключается мой глупый вопрос, собственно как это сделать?

Как бы я это не делал - не выходит, скорее всего это просто, но с нами частенько бывает, что пишешь сложный код, а впадаешь в тупняк на такой простой вещи...

Еще раз прошу прощение за глупый вопрос, и заранее спасибо)

Как это должно выглядеть в итоге:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В коде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Генерирую фон [trianglify](https://trianglify.io/):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1440" height="900"><path d="M755,523L648,518L768,637Z" fill="#f4fad6" stroke="#f4fad6" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M648,518L652,665L768,637Z" fill="#eef5d7" stroke="#eef5d7" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M652,665L766,802L768,637Z" fill="#ddeed8" stroke="#ddeed8" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M524,807L651,801L652,665Z" fill="#d5dfc5" stroke="#d5dfc5" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M648,518L481,641L652,665Z" fill="#f0edcc" stroke="#f0edcc" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M651,801L766,802L652,665Z" fill="#d5e5cf" stroke="#d5e5cf" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M755,523L769,367L648,518Z" fill="#fdfec4" stroke="#fdfec4" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M648,518L485,489L481,641Z" fill="#f6ecbe" stroke="#f6ecbe" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M928,525L769,367L755,523Z" fill="#f6fbd2" stroke="#f6fbd2" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M768,637L928,525L755,523Z" fill="#edf7e4" stroke="#edf7e4" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M766,802L906,693L768,637Z" fill="#d4ebe3" stroke="#d4ebe3" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M490,408L485,489L648,518Z" fill="#fdf0ae" stroke="#fdf0ae" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M906,693L928,525L768,637Z" fill="#e0f2f0" stroke="#e0f2f0" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M769,367L617,351L648,518Z" fill="#fff7b4" stroke="#fff7b4" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M617,351L490,408L648,518Z" fill="#fff2ab" stroke="#fff2ab" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M481,641L524,807L652,665Z" fill="#dfe1c2" stroke="#dfe1c2" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M651,801L636,938L766,802Z" fill="#c4d6c7" stroke="#c4d6c7" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M481,641L398,676L524,807Z" fill="#e1d7b8" stroke="#e1d7b8" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M346,531L398,676L481,641Z" fill="#f1d8b5" stroke="#f1d8b5" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M346,531L481,641L485,489Z" fill="#f8e0b2" stroke="#f8e0b2" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1101,656L1075,491L928,525Z" fill="#d5eced" stroke="#d5eced" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M766,802L924,812L906,693Z" fill="#c4e1e6" stroke="#c4e1e6" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M805,957L924,812L766,802Z" fill="#b8d4da" stroke="#b8d4da" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M928,525L945,361L769,367Z" fill="#f4f6d1" stroke="#f4f6d1" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M769,367L634,258L617,351Z" fill="#ffeea4" stroke="#ffeea4" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1075,491L945,361L928,525Z" fill="#e8f4db" stroke="#e8f4db" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M617,351L507,207L490,408Z" fill="#fee394" stroke="#fee394" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M801,231L634,258L769,367Z" fill="#feeba5" stroke="#feeba5" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M524,807L636,938L651,801Z" fill="#c6d0bd" stroke="#c6d0bd" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M505,971L636,938L524,807Z" fill="#bdc2b3" stroke="#bdc2b3" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M401,388L346,531L485,489Z" fill="#ffe09e" stroke="#ffe09e" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M401,388L485,489L490,408Z" fill="#ffe59c" stroke="#ffe59c" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M507,207L401,388L490,408Z" fill="#ffdc8d" stroke="#ffdc8d" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M398,676L384,768L524,807Z" fill="#dacfb1" stroke="#dacfb1" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M234,647L384,768L398,676Z" fill="#e4c8a9" stroke="#e4c8a9" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M945,361L801,231L769,367Z" fill="#f8edbb" stroke="#f8edbb" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M636,938L805,957L766,802Z" fill="#bacfc9" stroke="#bacfc9" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1101,656L928,525L906,693Z" fill="#d2ecf4" stroke="#d2ecf4" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1069,812L1101,656L906,693Z" fill="#b9e0ed" stroke="#b9e0ed" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1069,812L906,693L924,812Z" fill="#b8dceb" stroke="#b8dceb" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M805,957L917,933L924,812Z" fill="#accbdd" stroke="#accbdd" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M629,120L507,207L634,258Z" fill="#ffd285" stroke="#ffd285" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M634,258L507,207L617,351Z" fill="#ffde91" stroke="#ffde91" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M396,937L505,971L524,807Z" fill="#bfb9a9" stroke="#bfb9a9" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M636,938L755,1068L805,957Z" fill="#aebcc0" stroke="#aebcc0" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M917,933L1069,812L924,812Z" fill="#a8cfe4" stroke="#a8cfe4" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M945,361L948,210L801,231Z" fill="#f6e2bb" stroke="#f6e2bb" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1075,491L1089,390L945,361Z" fill="#e3edd2" stroke="#e3edd2" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1215,531L1089,390L1075,491Z" fill="#d4e9d9" stroke="#d4e9d9" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1052,257L948,210L945,361Z" fill="#ecdfbc" stroke="#ecdfbc" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M801,231L629,120L634,258Z" fill="#ffda91" stroke="#ffda91" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M507,207L367,267L401,388Z" fill="#fed081" stroke="#fed081" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M253,372L219,515L346,531Z" fill="#ffcd90" stroke="#ffcd90" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M384,768L396,937L524,807Z" fill="#cbc1ab" stroke="#cbc1ab" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M223,926L396,937L384,768Z" fill="#c7ae9b" stroke="#c7ae9b" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M346,531L234,647L398,676Z" fill="#f2ceab" stroke="#f2ceab" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M219,515L234,647L346,531Z" fill="#f9c8a2" stroke="#f9c8a2" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M758,82L629,120L801,231Z" fill="#ffd18e" stroke="#ffd18e" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M507,207L333,97L367,267Z" fill="#febc6d" stroke="#febc6d" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1089,390L1052,257L945,361Z" fill="#e5e5c5" stroke="#e5e5c5" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M805,957L915,1054L917,933Z" fill="#a0bad4" stroke="#a0bad4" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M917,933L1091,970L1069,812Z" fill="#98c2dd" stroke="#98c2dd" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M640,1116L755,1068L636,938Z" fill="#aaadb4" stroke="#aaadb4" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M640,1116L636,938L505,971Z" fill="#aeaeae" stroke="#aeaeae" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M253,372L346,531L401,388Z" fill="#ffd68d" stroke="#ffd68d" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M367,267L253,372L401,388Z" fill="#ffcd80" stroke="#ffcd80" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1101,656L1215,531L1075,491Z" fill="#c8e5e9" stroke="#c8e5e9" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1089,390L1183,351L1052,257Z" fill="#dbdfc2" stroke="#dbdfc2" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1220,768L1197,637L1101,656Z" fill="#acd6e8" stroke="#acd6e8" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M629,120L509,116L507,207Z" fill="#fec579" stroke="#fec579" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M367,267L196,251L253,372Z" fill="#febd72" stroke="#febd72" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M923,116L801,231L948,210Z" fill="#f8d4ab" stroke="#f8d4ab" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M923,116L758,82L801,231Z" fill="#fcce9c" stroke="#fcce9c" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M629,120L650,-19L509,116Z" fill="#ffb875" stroke="#ffb875" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M755,1068L915,1054L805,957Z" fill="#a0b1c8" stroke="#a0b1c8" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1069,812L1220,768L1101,656Z" fill="#a7d5e7" stroke="#a7d5e7" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1197,637L1215,531L1101,656Z" fill="#bbdeec" stroke="#bbdeec" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1071,120L923,116L948,210Z" fill="#efc8a8" stroke="#efc8a8" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M234,647L205,778L384,768Z" fill="#e0bca1" stroke="#e0bca1" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M105,638L205,778L234,647Z" fill="#e7b29b" stroke="#e7b29b" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M536,1116L640,1116L505,971Z" fill="#aa9ea4" stroke="#aa9ea4" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M755,1068L640,1116L915,1054Z" fill="#a3a6bc" stroke="#a3a6bc" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1215,531L1183,351L1089,390Z" fill="#d3e3cd" stroke="#d3e3cd" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1052,257L1071,120L948,210Z" fill="#e9cfad" stroke="#e9cfad" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1047,1075L1091,970L917,933Z" fill="#8cb0d4" stroke="#8cb0d4" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1197,637L1334,543L1215,531Z" fill="#b7d8e5" stroke="#b7d8e5" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1183,974L1220,768L1069,812Z" fill="#8ec1dc" stroke="#8ec1dc" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M379,1052L505,971L396,937Z" fill="#b5a29d" stroke="#b5a29d" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M379,1052L536,1116L505,971Z" fill="#ad9a9c" stroke="#ad9a9c" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M223,926L379,1052L396,937Z" fill="#b99a93" stroke="#b99a93" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M205,778L223,926L384,768Z" fill="#d0ad99" stroke="#d0ad99" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M205,778L53,834L223,926Z" fill="#cd998f" stroke="#cd998f" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M219,515L105,638L234,647Z" fill="#f5baa0" stroke="#f5baa0" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M64,501L105,638L219,515Z" fill="#f9b493" stroke="#f9b493" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1201,257L1071,120L1052,257Z" fill="#dfccad" stroke="#dfccad" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M764,-75L650,-19L758,82Z" fill="#fdb37c" stroke="#fdb37c" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1091,970L1183,974L1069,812Z" fill="#89b9d9" stroke="#89b9d9" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M915,1054L1047,1075L917,933Z" fill="#90add4" stroke="#90add4" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M640,1116L1047,1075L915,1054Z" fill="#99a3c8" stroke="#99a3c8" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1337,268L1201,257L1183,351Z" fill="#cccbb3" stroke="#cccbb3" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1183,351L1201,257L1052,257Z" fill="#d8d5b8" stroke="#d8d5b8" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M239,109L196,251L367,267Z" fill="#fdad63" stroke="#fdad63" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M66,397L64,501L219,515Z" fill="#feb682" stroke="#feb682" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M509,116L333,97L507,207Z" fill="#feb86c" stroke="#feb86c" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M758,82L650,-19L629,120Z" fill="#ffbd7e" stroke="#ffbd7e" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M764,-75L758,82L937,-44Z" fill="#f8ae89" stroke="#f8ae89" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M342,-28L333,97L509,116Z" fill="#fca05d" stroke="#fca05d" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1202,1088L1183,974L1091,970Z" fill="#75a1cd" stroke="#75a1cd" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1215,531L1380,413L1183,351Z" fill="#c6d9c9" stroke="#c6d9c9" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1344,635L1334,543L1197,637Z" fill="#acd0e5" stroke="#acd0e5" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1344,635L1197,637L1220,768Z" fill="#a2cee3" stroke="#a2cee3" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M66,397L219,515L253,372Z" fill="#ffbe80" stroke="#ffbe80" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1379,824L1344,635L1220,768Z" fill="#8ec1dc" stroke="#8ec1dc" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M88,228L66,397L196,251Z" fill="#fba464" stroke="#fba464" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M196,251L66,397L253,372Z" fill="#feb370" stroke="#feb370" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M333,97L239,109L367,267Z" fill="#fdaa5f" stroke="#fdaa5f" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M342,-28L239,109L333,97Z" fill="#fa9354" stroke="#fa9354" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M937,-44L758,82L923,116Z" fill="#f9b997" stroke="#f9b997" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M650,-19L522,-70L509,116Z" fill="#fca86a" stroke="#fca86a" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M223,926L230,1064L379,1052Z" fill="#b3898a" stroke="#b3898a" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M379,1052L230,1064L536,1116Z" fill="#ad888e" stroke="#ad888e" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M67,959L230,1064L223,926Z" fill="#b88084" stroke="#b88084" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M53,834L205,778L105,638Z" fill="#dda292" stroke="#dda292" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1040,-72L937,-44L1071,120Z" fill="#e9a894" stroke="#e9a894" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1071,120L937,-44L923,116Z" fill="#f0b69d" stroke="#f0b69d" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M505,-163L522,-70L668,-215Z" fill="#eb905d" stroke="#eb905d" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-89,672L53,834L105,638Z" fill="#dd9b8c" stroke="#dd9b8c" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-89,672L105,638L64,501Z" fill="#efa492" stroke="#efa492" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1334,543L1380,413L1215,531Z" fill="#bad3d2" stroke="#bad3d2" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1201,257L1194,83L1071,120Z" fill="#dabda1" stroke="#dabda1" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1471,493L1380,413L1334,543Z" fill="#b3c7ca" stroke="#b3c7ca" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1329,115L1194,83L1201,257Z" fill="#d0b39d" stroke="#d0b39d" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M239,109L88,228L196,251Z" fill="#fb9b5a" stroke="#fb9b5a" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1378,928L1379,824L1220,768Z" fill="#79b0d3" stroke="#79b0d3" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1047,1075L1202,1088L1091,970Z" fill="#799ecb" stroke="#799ecb" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M640,1116L1202,1088L1047,1075Z" fill="#8c9ccc" stroke="#8c9ccc" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M239,109L68,84L88,228Z" fill="#f9894f" stroke="#f9894f" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M522,-70L342,-28L509,116Z" fill="#fa9d5e" stroke="#fa9d5e" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1380,413L1337,268L1183,351Z" fill="#c3cbb9" stroke="#c3cbb9" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1344,635L1471,493L1334,543Z" fill="#aac6d9" stroke="#aac6d9" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1378,928L1220,768L1183,974Z" fill="#79afd2" stroke="#79afd2" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M53,834L67,959L223,926Z" fill="#c28886" stroke="#c28886" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1194,83L1040,-72L1071,120Z" fill="#e2aa97" stroke="#e2aa97" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M937,-44L819,-192L764,-75Z" fill="#f09e81" stroke="#f09e81" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1380,1049L1378,928L1183,974Z" fill="#6396c6" stroke="#6396c6" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M66,397L-80,493L64,501Z" fill="#f9aa79" stroke="#f9aa79" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M53,834L-41,964L67,959Z" fill="#bc7b7d" stroke="#bc7b7d" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M88,228L-29,362L66,397Z" fill="#f8a065" stroke="#f8a065" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M522,-70L505,-163L342,-28Z" fill="#f28c54" stroke="#f28c54" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M668,-215L522,-70L650,-19Z" fill="#f49a64" stroke="#f49a64" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M668,-215L650,-19L764,-75Z" fill="#f5a06d" stroke="#f5a06d" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1380,413L1461,265L1337,268Z" fill="#babaae" stroke="#babaae" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1475,684L1471,493L1344,635Z" fill="#9cbddc" stroke="#9cbddc" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1475,684L1344,635L1379,824Z" fill="#8ab7d7" stroke="#8ab7d7" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1516,832L1475,684L1379,824Z" fill="#77a6cf" stroke="#77a6cf" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-29,362L-80,493L66,397Z" fill="#f7a36e" stroke="#f7a36e" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1461,265L1329,115L1337,268Z" fill="#bfac9f" stroke="#bfac9f" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1337,268L1329,115L1201,257Z" fill="#c9b8a4" stroke="#c9b8a4" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1194,83L1218,-41L1040,-72Z" fill="#d99c8e" stroke="#d99c8e" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M908,-214L819,-192L937,-44Z" fill="#e69686" stroke="#e69686" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-80,493L-89,672L64,501Z" fill="#f0a087" stroke="#f0a087" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M88,228L-25,223L-29,362Z" fill="#f49459" stroke="#f49459" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M342,-28L220,-50L239,109Z" fill="#f6824c" stroke="#f6824c" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M234,-181L220,-50L342,-28Z" fill="#ed7041" stroke="#ed7041" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-89,672L-59,836L53,834Z" fill="#cf8c83" stroke="#cf8c83" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M819,-192L668,-215L764,-75Z" fill="#ea9973" stroke="#ea9973" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M67,959L67,1089L230,1064Z" fill="#b06c7b" stroke="#b06c7b" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M230,1064L67,1089L536,1116Z" fill="#ac7683" stroke="#ac7683" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-41,964L67,1089L67,959Z" fill="#af6a76" stroke="#af6a76" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M104,-9L68,84L239,109Z" fill="#f67747" stroke="#f67747" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-168,373L-175,542L-80,493Z" fill="#ea9972" stroke="#ea9972" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M68,84L-25,223L88,228Z" fill="#f4864d" stroke="#f4864d" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1040,-72L908,-214L937,-44Z" fill="#e7988a" stroke="#e7988a" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1329,115L1218,-41L1194,83Z" fill="#d09d90" stroke="#d09d90" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1378,928L1516,832L1379,824Z" fill="#6a9fca" stroke="#6a9fca" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1202,1088L1380,1049L1183,974Z" fill="#6591c4" stroke="#6591c4" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1218,-41L1069,-151L1040,-72Z" fill="#d89387" stroke="#d89387" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1520,362L1461,265L1380,413Z" fill="#b3b4af" stroke="#b3b4af" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1329,115L1351,-56L1218,-41Z" fill="#c88f88" stroke="#c88f88" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M819,-192L908,-214L668,-215Z" fill="#e09379" stroke="#e09379" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1069,-151L908,-214L1040,-72Z" fill="#db9187" stroke="#db9187" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-221,943L-41,964L-59,836Z" fill="#b26d75" stroke="#b26d75" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-59,836L-41,964L53,834Z" fill="#c07e7d" stroke="#c07e7d" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M68,84L-66,67L-25,223Z" fill="#ee7342" stroke="#ee7342" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M220,-50L104,-9L239,109Z" fill="#f57646" stroke="#f57646" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M118,-210L104,-9L220,-50Z" fill="#e95a39" stroke="#e95a39" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1471,493L1520,362L1380,413Z" fill="#b1bcbb" stroke="#b1bcbb" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1623,385L1520,362L1471,493Z" fill="#abaeb4" stroke="#abaeb4" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1475,684L1616,640L1471,493Z" fill="#93aed4" stroke="#93aed4" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1521,956L1516,832L1378,928Z" fill="#5d8fc2" stroke="#5d8fc2" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M505,-163L348,-202L342,-28Z" fill="#eb7e4b" stroke="#eb7e4b" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M668,-215L348,-202L505,-163Z" fill="#e18556" stroke="#e18556" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-89,672L-169,813L-59,836Z" fill="#ca8580" stroke="#ca8580" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-175,542L-166,659L-89,672Z" fill="#dc9188" stroke="#dc9188" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-175,542L-89,672L-80,493Z" fill="#e79785" stroke="#e79785" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-168,373L-80,493L-29,362Z" fill="#f09a68" stroke="#f09a68" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-229,215L-168,373L-25,223Z" fill="#e68352" stroke="#e68352" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-25,223L-168,373L-29,362Z" fill="#f0915a" stroke="#f0915a" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-166,659L-169,813L-89,672Z" fill="#ce8a84" stroke="#ce8a84" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-221,943L-169,813L-166,659Z" fill="#b97a7d" stroke="#b97a7d" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M348,-202L234,-181L342,-28Z" fill="#e77041" stroke="#e77041" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1643,809L1616,640L1475,684Z" fill="#7d9cca" stroke="#7d9cca" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1380,1049L1521,956L1378,928Z" fill="#5687bd" stroke="#5687bd" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1069,-151L1206,-216L908,-214Z" fill="#cc8884" stroke="#cc8884" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1218,-41L1206,-216L1069,-151Z" fill="#cb8681" stroke="#cb8681" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1520,121L1351,-56L1329,115Z" fill="#bf8a88" stroke="#bf8a88" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1520,121L1329,115L1461,265Z" fill="#ba9b93" stroke="#ba9b93" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1380,1049L1469,1083L1521,956Z" fill="#4c79b7" stroke="#4c79b7" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1202,1088L1469,1083L1380,1049Z" fill="#577db9" stroke="#577db9" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1608,1095L1469,1083L1202,1088Z" fill="#4d6fb2" stroke="#4d6fb2" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1643,809L1475,684L1516,832Z" fill="#7199c8" stroke="#7199c8" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-24,-33L68,84L104,-9Z" fill="#ed603c" stroke="#ed603c" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-24,-33L-66,67L68,84Z" fill="#eb5e3a" stroke="#eb5e3a" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1620,271L1520,121L1461,265Z" fill="#b09495" stroke="#b09495" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1616,640L1622,533L1471,493Z" fill="#9aa9cb" stroke="#9aa9cb" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-41,964L-90,1106L67,1089Z" fill="#a6576d" stroke="#a6576d" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M67,1089L-90,1106L536,1116Z" fill="#aa6378" stroke="#aa6378" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-221,943L-90,1106L-41,964Z" fill="#a35a6d" stroke="#a35a6d" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1620,271L1461,265L1520,362Z" fill="#ada2a2" stroke="#ada2a2" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1622,533L1623,385L1471,493Z" fill="#a6abbb" stroke="#a6abbb" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1371,-217L1206,-216L1351,-56Z" fill="#b57478" stroke="#b57478" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1351,-56L1206,-216L1218,-41Z" fill="#c5807e" stroke="#c5807e" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M908,-214L1206,-216L668,-215Z" fill="#d78e88" stroke="#d78e88" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-21,-165L-24,-33L104,-9Z" fill="#e24a31" stroke="#e24a31" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1616,640L1643,809L1622,533Z" fill="#8597ca" stroke="#8597ca" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1622,533L1656,107L1623,385Z" fill="#a895a1" stroke="#a895a1" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1641,941L1643,809L1516,832Z" fill="#5e83bd" stroke="#5e83bd" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1641,941L1516,832L1521,956Z" fill="#5681bb" stroke="#5681bb" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1656,107L1620,271L1623,385Z" fill="#aa8994" stroke="#aa8994" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1623,385L1620,271L1520,362Z" fill="#aa9ea4" stroke="#aa9ea4" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-169,813L-221,943L-59,836Z" fill="#b57479" stroke="#b57479" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-175,542L-221,943L-166,659Z" fill="#c88683" stroke="#c88683" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-229,215L-221,943L-175,542Z" fill="#da9084" stroke="#da9084" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M234,-181L118,-210L220,-50Z" fill="#e25a39" stroke="#e25a39" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M348,-202L118,-210L234,-181Z" fill="#da5c3c" stroke="#da5c3c" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M668,-215L118,-210L348,-202Z" fill="#dc7248" stroke="#dc7248" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-178,-78L-66,67L-24,-33Z" fill="#df4730" stroke="#df4730" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-178,-78L-177,131L-66,67Z" fill="#dd4f36" stroke="#dd4f36" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-66,67L-177,131L-25,223Z" fill="#e96d40" stroke="#e96d40" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-168,373L-229,215L-175,542Z" fill="#e28e62" stroke="#e28e62" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-177,131L-229,215L-25,223Z" fill="#e37446" stroke="#e37446" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1608,1095L1641,941L1521,956Z" fill="#456baf" stroke="#456baf" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-177,131L-178,-78L-229,215Z" fill="#d9583b" stroke="#d9583b" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M118,-210L-21,-165L104,-9Z" fill="#df4630" stroke="#df4630" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1469,1083L1608,1095L1521,956Z" fill="#436aaf" stroke="#436aaf" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M640,1116L1608,1095L1202,1088Z" fill="#718ec3" stroke="#718ec3" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1520,121L1523,-59L1351,-56Z" fill="#b6757d" stroke="#b6757d" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1665,-16L1523,-59L1520,121Z" fill="#ae6678" stroke="#ae6678" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1484,-184L1371,-217L1351,-56Z" fill="#ad6873" stroke="#ad6873" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1206,-216L1371,-217L668,-215Z" fill="#c68583" stroke="#c68583" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-90,1106L-221,1113L536,1116Z" fill="#a6536f" stroke="#a6536f" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-221,943L-221,1113L-90,1106Z" fill="#964968" stroke="#964968" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-229,215L-221,1113L-221,943Z" fill="#bd7e80" stroke="#bd7e80" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1665,-16L1656,107L1643,809Z" fill="#a78d99" stroke="#a78d99" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1643,809L1656,107L1622,533Z" fill="#a19fb8" stroke="#a19fb8" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1620,271L1656,107L1520,121Z" fill="#ad8088" stroke="#ad8088" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-21,-165L-178,-78L-24,-33Z" fill="#d93529" stroke="#d93529" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1647,-177L1484,-184L1523,-59Z" fill="#a0516a" stroke="#a0516a" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1523,-59L1484,-184L1351,-56Z" fill="#af6772" stroke="#af6772" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1656,107L1665,-16L1520,121Z" fill="#ac6a7c" stroke="#ac6a7c" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1641,941L1665,-16L1643,809Z" fill="#9399c9" stroke="#9399c9" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-21,-165L-165,-172L-178,-78Z" fill="#cc2827" stroke="#cc2827" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M-178,-78L-165,-172L-229,215Z" fill="#d23f31" stroke="#d23f31" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M118,-210L-165,-172L-21,-165Z" fill="#ce302a" stroke="#ce302a" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1665,-16L1647,-177L1523,-59Z" fill="#a34d6a" stroke="#a34d6a" stroke-width="1.51"/><path d="M1484,-184L1647,-177L1371,-217Z" fill="#9a556c" stroke="#9a556c" stroke-width="1.51"/></svg>
```

Через [yoksel](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/ru/) генерирую URL svg (можете закинуть попробовать, Stackoverflow не даёт больше 30к символов ввести)

Вы возможно спросите зачем мне всё это нужно если есть yoksel. Справедливо, но все же хочется всё автоматизировать под scss, чтобы для дальнейших функций по изменению цвета svg уже не было никаких костылей и копипасты каждого svg по новой.

Comment: Судя по коду нужно вставить inline-svg в параметр функции: `background-svg('<svg><path d="m0,0 h100 v100" /></svg>')`

Comment: Подозреваю, пропущен `url()`: `background-image: url(svg-url($svg));`

Comment: А нет, сорян, не приметил, все ок) А что получается в сгенерированной css? и где пример как вставляете?

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров и @НикитаУмнов, пробовал, по идее так и должно работать, потому как на все другие варианты линтер сразу ругается, а только про этот молчит. Но когда запускаю сервер при такой записи ничего не выводит. Пользуюсь галпом и browser-sync, там проблем нет, они всегда отлично работают. Так и подключаю: `@include background-svg('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1440" height="900"><path d="M755,...stroke-width="1.51"/></svg>');`

Comment: @НикитаУмнов, добавил внизу описания.

Comment: С виду все ок. Замените еще пробелы на %20, в некоторых браузерах это тоже не приветствуется

Comment: Прикрепите полный код того что сгенерировалось в url(), так сложно угадывать

Comment: @НикитаУмнов сделал, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: @AlexPriest извиняюсь за долгий ответ. А функция `str-replace` у вас описана?

Comment: @НикитаУмнов да ничего, мне ведь не горит. Но да, естественно она у меня есть.

Comment: Странно, я генерирую этими же функциями - все хорошо. Проблема с любыми svg, или конкретно с этой?

Answer (score 0):

Добавить функцию `str-replace`

```
/// Replace `$search` with `$replace` in `$string`
/// @author Hugo Giraudel
/// @param {String} $string - Initial string
/// @param {String} $search - Substring to replace
/// @param {String} $replace ('') - New value
/// @return {String} - Updated string
@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: '') {
  $index: str-index($string, $search);

  @if $index {
    @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + $replace + str-replace(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search, $replace);
  }

  @return $string;
}
```